# Data sources for species co-occurrences in soundscapes?

Tags: dataset

I'd like to find online data in which 2 different species sing/call in the same soundscape. This is not a machine learning question! - I'm looking for data that have already been tagged with those species.

It's possible to search for this data in Xeno-canto, but I need 3 separate queries (allowing for "foreground" and "background" occurrences):

```
Turdus merula also:"Troglodytes troglodytes"
Troglodytes troglodytes also:"Turdus merula"
also:"Troglodytes troglodytes" also:"Turdus merula"
```

These 3 queries currently get me 620/573/13 results. (I also asked this question directly [on the XC forum](https://xeno-canto.org/forum/topic/54112).)

I also tried a [GBIF](https://www.gbif.org/) search but it combines species using "OR" but I'd need "AND".

Are there any other ways, or other data sources, in which I can search for an arbitrary 2 species vocalising in the same audio clips?

Comment: do you need calls from any taxonomic groups? or mainly birds?

Comment: Birds is my target group. (I'm asking the question generally, hopefully to find different databases, though in the end I'd be testing with birds.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you specifically looking for queriable databases? Or would labelled data you can download also interest you?

Ocean Networks Canada has a labelled data set you can access by contacting them to get a spreadsheet of the labels and using their API tools to download the associated files from their online archive. The data set is from a location that often records multiple species calling at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any databases providing this info through queries but I expect that this will be available soon. Meanwhile you could consult the data available in one of my paper, where bird communities from temperate forest are described (Table A3 in appendices, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0006320715002414). If any files are of interests, contact the author (amandine.gasc at ird.fr) as the data are open and stored in the sound library of the national museum of Paris.

Answer (score 1):

Another computationally accessible data source is Xeno-Canto, which has [a convenient API](https://xeno-canto.org/help/search).

You can search for recordings of specific species, genera, or families. With the `also:` query you can specify a background species, genera, or family. So, if you wanted to search quite generally for recordings of New World Sparrows with New World Warblers in the background, that might look like:

`'https://www.xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=passerellidae&also:parulidae'`

Which returned >15000 results when I ran it. There is no guarantee that the vocalizations will overlap, but at least it's a fast way to narrow your search. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a growing body of publicly available annotated soundscape data. As I mentioned in response to [this question](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/searching-natural-examples-of-bird-a-background-bird-b/1384#1384), here are a few to get you started:

https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ecy.3329

https://www.beei.org/index.php/EEI/article/view/5243

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1574954123000432

https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ecy.4047

Comment: Thanks for the dataset suggestions, but it's not clear from this which ones answer my question: I'm looking for **an arbitrary 2 species vocalising in the same audio clip**. I'm pretty sure that papers 2 and 3 in your list do NOT offer this, since the dataset is one-label-per-audio-clip. I think items 1 and 4 may contain appropriate data (though not in the searchable manner I was hoping for) - I'll look into them.